# crontab does not run my python script

Tags: python, cron

My python script is not running under my Crontab. But when i try to run it from the Terminal it works perfectly. I have placed this in the python script at the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Also I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

I did my file executable:

```
chmod a+x vida.py
```

Added to my crontab and added PATH:

```
USER=gg
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin/:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin/:/home/gg/DC.bin/:/home/gg/GNSSMET/DC/:usr/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/:/home/gg/GNSSMET/DC/bin/:/home/gg/:/usr/lib/python2.7/:
PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/:/usr/lib/python2.7/

*/1 *  * * *    gg   /usr/bin/python /home/gg/vida.py 2>&1 >>/home/gg/out1.txt
```

I checked the log via `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

```
Jan 19 13:37:01 gg-pc CRON[26500]: (gg) CMD ( /usr/bin/python /home/gg/vida.py 2>&1 >>/home/gg/out1.txt)
```

I even run a dummy python script from using crontab and it worked like charm (simple Hello, World!). But when it comes to my script the output file `out1.txt` is created (which is empty) but does not run the actual script. I even checked all of the solutions presented on StackOverflow, none did work.
So here is my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from datetime import *
import os
import sys

gamitRinexDir = '/home/gg/GAMIT/rinex'
stalist = ['ankr','argi','aut1','beug','brst','bucu','busk','ganm','gism','glsv','gmlk','gope','hofn','ingl','ista','joze',
'kiru','krcy','ktvl','mas1','mate','mets','mkps','morp','nico','onsa','orhn','orid','pdel','penc','polv','pots','puyv',
'sofi','vis0','vlns','wtzr','yebe','zeck','zimm']

letlist = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X']
seslist = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
tnow  = datetime.now()
dback = timedelta(hours=2)
tnow  = tnow -dback
wlength = 4

os.system('rm ' + gamitRinexDir + '/*')
wlett   = []
updir   = []
doylist = []
yrlist  = []
for i in range(wlength):
   delta = timedelta(hours=i+1)
   tback = tnow -delta
   wlett.append(letlist[tback.hour])
   doystr = 'doy ' + str(tnow.year) + ' ' + str(tnow.month) + ' ' + str(tnow.day) + ' ' + '> /home/gg/sil.sil'
   os.system(doystr)
   fid = open('/home/gg/sil.sil')
   line  = fid.readline().split()
   doynum = '%03d' % (int(line[5]))
   x      = str(tnow.year)
   yrnum  = x[2:4]
   updir.append(yrnum+doynum)
   doylist.append(doynum)
   yrlist.append(yrnum)

dirname = '/home/gg/REPO/nrtdata/'
for i in range(len(wlett)):
    adirname = dirname + updir[i]+'/' + wlett[i]
    for sta in stalist:  
        fname  = adirname      + '/' + sta + doylist[i] + wlett[i].lower() + '.' + yrlist[i]+'d.Z'
        fname2 = gamitRinexDir + '/' + sta + doylist[i] + seslist[i]       + '.' + yrlist[i]+'d.Z'
        os.system('cp ' + fname + ' ' + fname2)

udoy = list(set(doylist))
dcmd = ''
for gun in udoy:
    dcmd = dcmd + gun + ' '    

CmdGamit = 'sh_gamit -d ' + x + ' ' + dcmd + ' ' + '-orbit IGSU -expt expt -eops usnd -gnss G -nopngs -metutil Z'
print(CmdGamit)
mainCmd = 'cd /home/gg/GAMIT/;'+CmdGamit
os.system(mainCmd)
filestocopy1 = 'met_*'
filestocopy2 = 'hexpta.*'
filestocopy3 = 'uexpt*'
ndirname = ' /home/gg/REPO_GAMIT/' + doynum + '_'+ wlett[-1]
os.system('mkdir ' + ndirname)
cleancmd1 = 'mv /home/gg/GAMIT/'+doynum +'/'+filestocopy1 + ' ' + ndirname
cleancmd2 = 'mv /home/gg/GAMIT/'+doynum +'/'+filestocopy2 + ' ' + ndirname
cleancmd3 = 'mv /home/gg/GAMIT/'+doynum +'/'+filestocopy3 + ' ' + ndirname
cleancmd4 = 'rm -r /home/gg/GAMIT/'+doynum
os.system(cleancmd1)
os.system(cleancmd2)
os.system(cleancmd3)
os.system(cleancmd4)
```

Please show me some pointers, I am seriously stuck here.

Comment: A possible next step might be to remove all your code from the script and slowly start adding it until your script stops working again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change you crontab line as such to get `stdout` and `stderr` saved to the file:

```
*/1 *  * * *    gg   /usr/bin/python /home/gg/vida.py >> /home/gg/out1.txt 2>&1
```

Simply read `out1.txt` after crontab has run the line to see what's wrong

Edit after your comment:
Based on the error you've shared, I believe you're not actually writing anything in the `/home/gg/sil.sil` file:

```
doystr = 'doy ' + str(tnow.year) + ' ' + str(tnow.month) + ' ' + str(tnow.day) + ' ' + '> /home/gg/sil.sil'
os.system(doystr)
```

`doystr` does not evaluate to a shell command, I think you need to write the variable as below to write to the file.

```
doystr = 'echo "doy ' + str(tnow.year) + ' ' + str(tnow.month) + ' ' + str(tnow.day) + '" ' + '> /home/gg/sil.sil'
```

Comment: sh: 1: doy: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gg/vida.py", line 38, in <module>
    doynum = '%03d' % (int(line[5]))
IndexError: list index out of range



This is the output of crontab run but why ? i mean in normal terminal script run it works without any problem.

Comment: @GökhanGürbüz it implies that `/home/gg/sil.sil` doesn't contain the same thing running directly or from cron... Find out what's going on there...

Comment: This is the answer you are looking for. You were previously simply losing the error message, and now you are not losing it. It tells you that there is a problem in your code, and now you know.

Comment: Maybe point out specifically that putting `2>&1` *before* the stdout redirection is wrong for this scenario. You want to redirect stderr and stdout to a file, not redirect stdout to the file and then send errors to the old stderr (which apparently isn't connected anywhere useful, though technically, `cron` will try to send you those messages by email).

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. In the end after these modifications it was still giving me errors but mainly it was due to PATH definitions of crontab. The software that i was calling within python required PATH in crontab also. So it is working now. Thank you @AnythingIsFine, JonClements, tripleee.

Answer (score -1):

syntax:

minutes hour dom mon dow user  command

55 16   * * *   root    /root/anaconda/bin/python /root/path/file_name.py &>> /root/output/output.log